# Unable to type in Arduino IDE running on OS X

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm trying to use the Arduino IDE (1.6.8 downloaded from arduino.cc) on a MacBook running OS X (10.11.5 beta).

The IDE seems to run and I can open and upload the examples and they run. But…

I can't type in the editor window of the IDE – either with the examples or with the new sketch that opens when you launch the IDE.

I have a similar problem with the version of the IDE distributed with mBlock (1.6.5) if I use the Edit in Arduino IDE button. I also tried the 1.6.9 hourly version. All to no avail. So I'm thinking that this is a OS X problem, or maybe an issue with version of Java (1.8.0).

Any ideas or troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: Make sure that in `preferences` the option `Use external editor` is **not** checked. You could also try downloading an older version.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I'd forgotten I'd done that. Make it an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that in `preferences` the option `Use external editor` is **not** checked.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution on this forum [http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=93338.]
File | Preferences | Use External Editor (Don't use)

Comment: This is the same solution as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you may also consider Sublime Text -> with the STino plug-in, it is a full-fledged editor that does everything your arduino IDE does, in a much more stylish way.